# accidentially modifying the binary of a file whilst it is running

Tags: nfs, bsd

I have several FreeBSD boxes mix of V10 and V11 that all have some binaries mounted over nfs. unfortunately a situation came about when one was executed whilst it was still being uploaded to the nfs server.

I would have expected the processes to crash, but the result is multiple instances of the process in a wait state of `vmpfw` and attempting to ls the directory containing the binaries, of sym links to causes the shell to freeze

Ive done a power cycle on all machines that I can to clear this, but there are a few where this is going to be exceedingly inconvienient. Is there any way of killing these processes, and restoring responsiveness

Comment: try with umount -f

Comment: @kofemann I tried that on the mount that contained the binary. The command takes infinite time, seemingly going into yet another uninteruptable sleep